# Warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast in struct

Tags: c, struct, warnings

I'm doing a program calculating the negative of a PGM image and save it in other PGM image.I'm getting this warning in the lines

```
 (argv[5]) = (imagem->l - 1);
 (argv[6]) = (imagem->c - 1);
```

My code (main.c):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "declarations.h" 

typedef struct  
{
  int c; 
  int l; 
  unsigned char **matrizPixels; 
} PGM;

/*command line:
./exec input output x0 y0 x1 y1
argv0  argv1   argv2 argv3 argv4 argv5 argv6*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  PGM *imagem = (PGM*)malloc(sizeof(PGM));

  imagem = (PGM*) lePGM(argv[1]);

  /* if there isn't x0,y0,x1,y1... */
  if ( (!(argv[3])) && (!(argv[4])) && (!(argv[5])) && (!(argv[6])) )  
  {
    /* (x0,y0) will be (0,0) */
    (argv[3]) = 0;
    (argv[4]) = 0;

    /* (x1,y1) will be (line-1,colunm-1) */
    (argv[5]) = (imagem->l - 1);
    (argv[6]) = (imagem->c - 1);
  }

  NegativoRegiao(imagem, atoi(argv[3]), atoi(argv[4]), atoi(argv[5]), atoi(argv[6]) );

  salvaPGM(imagem, argv[2]);

  free (imagem); 

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: What is the program supposed to do? You can not assign a pointer to null and then access that null pointer as if it had a string with an integer in it.

Answer (score 1):

`argv[n]` is of type `char*` but for instance `imagem->l` is an `int`
so I would declare some extra variables and use them instead of trying to re-use argv (especially in a case where you just verified it didn't exist)

you can inspect `argc` to see whether enough arguments are provided

the code can be made more robust by also checking the value returned by `malloc` successful

EDIT: something along these lines

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
int x0, y0, x1, y1;

PGM *imagem = malloc(sizeof(PGM));
if (imagem == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (argc < 3) {
  fprintf(stderr, "missing commandline parameters\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

imagem = (PGM*) lePGM(argv[1]);

if (argc < 7) {
  // print warning ?
  // set defaults
  x0 = y0 = 0;
  x1 = (imagem->l - 1);
  y1 = (imagem->c - 1);
}

NegativoRegiao(imagem, x0, y0, x1, y1);

salvaPGM(imagem, argv[2]);

free (imagem);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I tried to declare:                                                    char* lineX1, colY1;                                                            linhaX1 = (imagem->l - 1); 
     colunaY1 = (imagem->c - 1); 
     
     (argv[5]) = linhaX1;
     (argv[6]) = colunaY1; didnt work